# PUT and POST Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, wcf, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic project with a WCF RESTful service, I want to be able to Insert and Update data. I can already view data with GET method but can't find anything on the internet for PUT and POST. How would I be able to accomplish this?

**GET Method**

```
$scope.selectedDist=  function() {


                 $http.get("http://192.168.1.113/Service1.svc/GetAllComp")
              .success(function(data) {

              var obj = data;
              var ar = [];
              angular.forEach(obj, function(index, element) {

              angular.forEach(index, function(indexN, elementN) {


                 ar.push({CompID: indexN.CompID, CompName: indexN.CompName});

                  $scope.districts = ar;
              }); 
              });

            })

          .error(function(data) {
              console.log("failure");})    


       };
```

**Post methods I tried**

**#1**

```
 $scope.insertdata = function() {
       var ar = [{'M1':$scope.M1, 'M2':$scope.M2,'M3':$scope.M3,'M4':$scope.M4,'M5':$scope.M5,'M6':$scope.M6,'M7':$scope.M7,'M8':$scope.M8,'M9':$scope.M9,'M10':$scope.M10,}]


     $http.post("http://192.168.1.113/Service1.svc/GetAllComp", ar)
       .success(function(data)
         {
           console.log("data inserted successfully")
         })
         .error(function(data)
           {
             console.log("Error")
           })
```

**#2**

```
$scope.insertdata = function() {
       var ar = [{'M1':$scope.M1, 'M2':$scope.M2,'M3':$scope.M3,'M4':$scope.M4,'M5':$scope.M5,'M6':$scope.M6,'M7':$scope.M7,'M8':$scope.M8,'M9':$scope.M9,'M10':$scope.M10,}]

$http ({ 
    url : "localhost:15021/Service1.svc/TruckDetails" , 
    Method :  "POST" , 
    headers :  { 
        'Content-Type' :  'Application / json; charset = utf-8' 
    }, 
    Data :  ar 
})
```

Also Would I need to make a POST or PUT method on my Service as well or can I use the GET methods?

Comment: please see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put

Comment: That was the first thing I looked at when doing post and dit get it to work when I was testing with an array but I can't figure out how to use it with a Service. @sylwester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** use a get method, in combination with a querystring to post and put data but that is **not** what it was [designed](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) for and should be avoided for several reasons such as security.

That being said, it is not that difficult to use post and put in angular and in the following , rather naive service , you can see all that is required to do is passing your data in the service function you're invoking.

```
.service('MyService', function($http) {

     this.postMethod = function(data) {
         return $http.post('http://my.url', data);
     };

     this.putMethod = function(id, data) {
         return $http.put('http://my.url/' + id, data);
     };
}
```

So that in your controller you can inject and invoke the service methods with the `$scope` data that needs to be stored.

After taking a look at your attempts you seem to be using the same url for both get and post: `"http://192.168.1.113/Service1.svc/GetAllComp"` which actually leads me to believe you haven't thought about implementing these methods on your server. Can you confirm this?

Apart from that, it is always usefull to look at statuscodes when trying to send requests because they provide a great deal of information about the nature of the error that occurs. You can investigate that in either your console or an external program such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

P.S.

> Deprecation Notice The $http legacy promise methods success and error
>   have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Comment: Thanks your answer is very insightful! So I Should create a POST & PUT method from my service and call it the way you showed above? @skubski

Comment: Yes, you should begin with creating the server-side PUT and POST operations in order to be able to call them in your client-side AngularJS application. Once you feel like you're done, you can test the operations with something like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) before you implement a AngularJS service that will communicate with it! @RenaldoGeldenhuis